# How to publish artifacts in Travis CI?

Tags: artifacts, travis-ci

I would like to use [Travis CI](http://travis-ci.org/) for my open-source project. The issue that Travis doesn't provide any ways to publish produced artifacts (though, they have this in their future plans).

What are workarounds to publish/upload artifacts somewhere? I'm allowed to execute any scripts on a CI machine.

Simple upload will work, but there is security issue: anyone will be able to upload something in the same way as all sources are public.

Comment: Several years later, I think Travis implemented what you are looking for, though it's currently limited to uploading to S3: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/uploading-artifacts/

Comment: Use this in conjunction with @NickChammas 's link:  https://github.com/travis-ci/artifacts/blob/master/upload/options.go 
Their documentation doesn't mention half of the parameters that the `artifacts` addon actually accepts.

Comment: Travis also now offers a pretty easy to set up github-pages option, see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277391/how-to-publish-to-github-pages-from-travis-ci/42934887#42934887

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The "github releases uploading" feature is announced recently. It officially supports everything that is needed. See http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/releases/

Comment: A detailed step-by-step of how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33109519/895245

Comment: Except for being able to just upload something to a tag only, without making it a release... :(

Answer (score 43):

**GitHub releases step-by-step**

The method was mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24100779/895245, and is poorly documented at: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/releases/ , so here goes a more detailed step-by-step.

It uploads artifacts to GitHub releases `https://github.com/<username>/<repo>/releases` which exist for every Git tag you push.

1. Get a Personal Access Token under https://github.com/settings/tokens

   Only enable "public_repo" access for public repositories, "repo" for private.

   Save the token somewhere as you can only see it once.
2. Install the `travis` gem:

   ```
   gem install travis
   # See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33119804/895245
   gem update --system
   ```

   Then `cd` into your repository and:

   ```
   travis encrypt <api-token>
   ```

   but more recently people have reported that `travis encrypt -r githubusername/repositoryname --org` is needed instead, see: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/8128

   This will produce an output like:

   ```
   secure: "<encrypted-token>"
   ```

   Note down the large encrypted token.
3. Use a `.travis.yml` as follows:

   ```
   script:
     # This command generates a release.zip file.
     - make dist
   deploy:
     provider: releases
     api_key:
       secure: "<encrypted-token>"
     file: 'release.zip'
     skip_cleanup: true
     on:
       tags
   ```

   What happens is that Travis replaces every `something: secure: <encrypted-string>` with just `something: <decrypted-string>` as explained at: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/

   This is safe because only authorized pushes by you can decrypt the string, so if a malicious user tries to make a pull request to get your string, it would should just show the encrypted string.

   Now whenever you push a commit with a tag, Travis will upload `release.zip` to the release:

   ```
   git commit -m 1.0
   git tag -m 1.0 1.0
   git push --tags
   ```

   If you had already pushed the commit and the tag after, you might have to click the "Restart build" button on the Travis UI for it to upload.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38037626/895245 has some screenshots of the process.

**Alternative method: environment variable**

1. Instead of an encrypted string, we could also use a hidden environment variable.

   On the Travis settings for the repository `https://travis-ci.org/<me>/<myrepo>/settings` create an environment variable:

   ```
   GITHUB_API_KEY=<token>
   ```

   and make sure to mark "Display value in build log" as "Off", and use:

   ```
   api_key: '$GITHUB_API_KEY'
   ```

   While this will not show on logs for pull requests, this method is riskier, as you could my mistake list the environment of a build.

   The upside is that this method is simpler to understand.

A simple example of mine that uploads images generated from Gnuplot to GitHub releases:

- https://github.com/cirosantilli/gnuplot-examples/blob/b76d5a7c7aa2af973accdc9639220df74c36285e/.travis.yml#L23
- https://github.com/cirosantilli/gnuplot-cheat/releases

Question about GitHub Pages deployment: [How to publish to Github Pages from Travis CI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277391/pushing-to-github-from-travis-ci)

Comment: after long time search, i found the encrypt command is wrong, better `travis encrypt -r githubusername/repositoryname --org`, see [travis issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/8128)

Answer (score 10):

If your project is based on GitHub - likely with Travis - then the easiest way is to check in the generated artifacts under the `gh-pages` branch. See more on [GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/what-are-github-pages).

How to do that depends a lot on the used build system. With Maven, you can use `maven-scm-plugin` - you can find an example [here](https://github.com/tonnymadsen/ui-bindings/tree/master/com.rcpcompany.uibindings.updatesite).

EDIT: You can find a full example here: https://github.com/tonnymadsen/ui-bindings/blob/master/com.rcpcompany.updatesite/pom.xml

Comment: This requires storing Git authentication data publicly in a repo, doesn't it?

Comment: Sorts of... See section "Secure environment variables" on <a href="http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/build-configuration/">this Travis page</a>.

Comment: Secure environment vars seems to be a new feature I didn't know. Thanks!

Comment: Updated link: http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/build-configuration/#Secure-environment-variables

Comment: This article explains in detail how to automatically push to gh-pages : https://gist.github.com/domenic/ec8b0fc8ab45f39403dd

Answer (score 8):

So first you have to be sure that you try to deploy release artifacts. So make tag first in Github. To do it manually:

[image]

Then in the `.travis.yml` file add the following configuration. For gradle users

```
language: java
jdk:
  - oraclejdk7

sudo: required

before_install:
 - chmod +x gradlew

script:
  - ./gradlew clean build -i --continue

deploy:
  provider: releases
  api_key: ${api_key}
  file: "build/libs/Project.jar"
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    all_branches: true
    tags: true
```

Here **api_key** value is *Travis Ci* environment variable. Which points to Github api_key.

**file** is the build artifact produced from the build. Which we want to be deployed to **gitHub**.

```
on:
    all_branches: true
    tags: true
```

is mandatory configuration for tags to be deployed.

No you have to get the api_key from github:

1. Go to **Personal Access Tokens**

[image]

2. Choose **Generate new token**

[image]

3. Select appropriate scopes for the **api_key**
   [image]
4. Copy the generated api_key
   [image]
5. Go to the Travis Ci and add environment variable. For that purpose choose **Settings**
   [image]

   6. Paste the generated **api_key**
      [image]

When you trigger new build the artifact will be deployed.
[image]

Comment: I had explained the method at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33109519/895245 , but you have screenshots, so get a +1.

Answer (score 6):

**Update**: GitHub disable the Download API now, so below answer is idea.

My solution is using "secure environment variables" provided by travis-ci and "GitHub repo Download API" with related script

Each repo in GitHub has download pages, it is also the good place to publish your artifacts, and it has related "Repo Download API" http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/downloads/

- Secure environment variable can refer to another question: [Add secret environment variable to Travis CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724139/add-secret-environment-variable-to-travis-ci)
- Use the nice script `github-upload.rb` from https://github.com/wereHamster/ghup to manage the GitHub API.

In the end, in the `.travis-ci.yml` it looks like below

```
env:
  global:
    - secure: "qkE5/TVKQV/+xBEW5M7ayWMMtFwhu44rQb9zh3n0LH4CkVb+b748lOuW3htc\nXfnXU8aGzOsQBeCJZQstfzsHFPkll+xfhk38cFqNQp7tpMo/AOZIkqd2AIUL\n0bgaFD+1kFAxKTu02m11xzkDNw6FuHMVvoMEQu/fo115i2YmWHo="  

after_script:
  - ./github-upload.rb sdcamp.zh.pdf larrycai/sdcamp --description "generated by travis-ci, $TRAVIS_JOB_ID" --force --name sdcamp.zh.snapshot.pdf --skip-ssl-verification -t $GITHUB_TOKEN
```

see my detail blog: http://larrycaiyu.com/blog/2012/10/25/publish-the-artifacts-inside-travis-ci-to-github/

Comment: Github has disabled the upload/download feature:Please read this new post: https://github.com/blog/1302-goodbye-uploads

Comment: noticed this, then it is not possible for any solution, you can answer this question directly

Comment: I am not sure to give my comment as an answer because some poeple does deploy artifacts into the gh-pages branch via check in (see accepted answer). In my mind it is not ok but it is a solution.

Answer (score 6):

I realize this is an older question, but I'd like to add another solution to the mix that I believe to be better than the ones discussed thus far.

### Use Bintray:

The OP is interested in *publishing* artifacts from Travis-CI.  I recommend using **https://bintray.com/** with either [an organization](https://bintray.com/docs/usermanual/interacting/interacting_bintrayorganizations.html), or your own personal account (both work, but in the case of a github org, it might make more sense to have an organization that matches it, and published artifacts from that github org go to it's matching bintray org).

The reason for this is because of what bintray offers and it's support for open source projects.  I recommend you take a look here at their overview: http://www.jfrog.com/bintray/

You can also [link to JCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter), which makes what you publish much easier for anyone else to consume/download/use (via maven, gradle, SBT, etc).

### For Java + Maven:

Once you have bintray setup (your account created or an org), you can easily integrate it with travis.  For java & maven builds, you can use [travis-ci's encrypted variables](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/) option to encrypt the `${BINTRAY_USER}` and `${BINTRAY_API_KEY}`.  Then you can [set up maven](https://github.com/bintray/bintray-examples/blob/f35b02106471630053c7f5c1b2bf43894fe94f85/maven-example/settings.xml#L4-L10) deploy to push releases into bintray.  In the maven `settings.xml` file, you'll just reference the environment variables you encrypted with travis as the user/pass, ie:

```
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>my-bintray-id</id>
      <username>${env.BINTRAY_USER}</username>
      <password>${env.BINTRAY_API_KEY}</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
```

Next, you'll add the `distributionManagement` section to your project's `pom.xml`, something like this:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>my-bintray-id</id>
        <url>https://api.bintray.com/maven/myUserName/myRepoName/my_awesome_project;publish=1</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Then you will set up your `.travis.yml` file to "detect" when there is a release.  I've used the first half of the [maven release plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html): `mvn release:prepare` (ignoring the second half -- release:preform) from your local dev box.  This will make a tag, bump the version in the pom, etc, on your behalf.  What you end up with is a tag of a *version* (not -SNAPSHOT) in github.  This tagged commit makes its way downstream to travis, where your `.travis.yml` will configure Travis to build & publish.

In your `.travis.yml`, configure it to test for a `TRAVIS_TAG`, `TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST`, and [any other checks](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/#Environment-variables) you want to make *before* calling `mvn deploy`.  You would do this on `after_success`.  This way, travis builds **all** the time, but **only runs** `mvn deploy` when it's a tag and meets other conditions you want (like for instance, a JDK8 build).  Here's an example `.travis.yml`:

```
language: java

jdk:
  - oraclejdk7
  - oraclejdk8

after_success:
  - mvn clean cobertura:cobertura coveralls:report javadoc:jar
  - test "${TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST}" == "false" && test "${TRAVIS_TAG}" != "" && mvn deploy --settings travis-settings.xml

branches:
  only:
    - master
      # Build tags that match this regex in addition to building the master branch.
    - /^my_awesome_project-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/

env:
  global:
    - secure: 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
    - secure: 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
```

(The secure's are just a made up example, after you encrypt your bintray user and [bintray api key](https://bintray.com/docs/usermanual/interacting/interacting_editingyouruserprofile.html#anchorAPIKEY) with travis, you'll see something similar in your yaml)

This gets you a full end to end system for publishing artifacts "into the wild" where anyone can then consume and use.  You're using a service that is *designed* from the ground up as an artifact repository (bintray), and you are using Travis *in a smart way* to check for tags that maven release:prepare produces.  All together, you decide when releases are made (`mvn release:prepare` from your local dev box), and travis gets them to bintray.

### Other

Note that there's an existing [travis-ci/dpl pull request](https://github.com/travis-ci/dpl/pull/259) in github to get tighter integration (travis providers) between Travis and bintray built.  This makes it much easier to have travis send artifacts to bintray (**releases**; bintray wasn't intended to hold SNAPSHOTs, use [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/open-source/) for that instead).  Even though github has some support for releases, as of this writing, I believe bintray to be superior in this role, and the right tool to use.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I've put together an example project at https://github.com/vorburger/mvnDeployGitHubTravisCI illustrating how to do this (partially based on [Hosting a Maven repository on github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013644/hosting-a-maven-repository-on-github/)). As explained on the linked answer, the basic idea is to prepare a local repository using the [maven-deploy-plugin's altDeploymentRepository](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html#altDeploymentRepository), and then use the [github site-maven-plugin](https://github.com/github/maven-plugins) to push your artifacts to GitHub.  Connect Travis to GitHub authentication as explained above.

Comment: @kleopatra thank you; better now? ;-) I'm still new to SO.. does one actually get karma for reacting to such suggestions?

Comment: virtual karma, certainly :-) Well, actually, it can be the other way round: posts with nothing more than a link are in danger of being deleted (if somebody deems them not helpful enough)

Answer (score 2):

TravisCI now supports releases: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/releases/

GitHub removed the Download API, but replaced it with releases: https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software

Comment: Does this answer add anything new to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24100779/895245 + http://stackoverflow.com/a/13067390/895245 ? :-)

Answer (score 0):

The integration SBT-Travis-Sonatype consists of the following main steps:

1. Adding sbt-pgp plugin;
2. Generating key pair for signing your artifacts and publishing it on a public key server;
3. Encrypting the key pair and sonatype credential files and adding them to your project;
4. Creating travis configuration and adding the encrypted key used by Travis to unpack your secret files.

I put together a simple instruction on how to integrate SBT with Travis-CI and Sonatype, it is available [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xjCQz10kQtievwSra-aLhNmLEeEwNSm55zY6Qd92IHs/edit#heading=h.nj23sjpj5u97) and contains the necessary steps from configuring the project plugins to encrypting the files and providing Travis configuration. It is mostly based on John Duffel’s [developer blog](https://www.theguardian.com/info/developer-blog/2014/sep/16/shipping-from-github-to-maven-central-and-s3-using-travis-ci) combined with sbt-pgp reference docs.

Answer (score 0):

The first question you should ask yourself is whether you want to publish artifacts from CI builds or whether you want to deploy releases (i.e. to GitHub).

Since there are plenty of answers here regarding uploading releases to GitHub, I will not tackle this topic further.

If you want to get hold of snapshot/CI build artifacts, the easiest way is to have them uploaded to AWS S3. Unfortunately, [the documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/uploading-artifacts/) for this is a bit rough, especially when you are unexperienced with AWS. So here is what you have to do:

**1. Create a AWS IAM user for Travis**

To do so, go to https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#/users and create a new user account for Travis with type Programmatic access. Grant it access to S3 by applying the existing policy *AmazonS3FullAccess* on the permissions tab.

Once the user is created make sure to copy the *Access Key ID* as well the *secret access key* for that user!

**2. Create a AWS S3 Bucket for Travis to upload to**

That one is pretty straight forward. Only thing to watch out for is to **avoid Signature v4-only regions** like `us-east-2`, `eu-central-1`, etc. (because of https://github.com/travis-ci/artifacts/issues/57). A solid choice is `us-east-1`, which also happens to be the default expected by Travis and thus saves you a little additional configuration. Of course you can also use an existing bucket that meets this requirement.

**3. Add environment variables to Travis CI repository settings**

Next, go to the settings for your repository in Travis. Create the following new environment variables:

```
ARTIFACTS_KEY=(AWS access key id from step 1)
ARTIFACTS_SECRET=(AWS secret access key from step 1)
ARTIFACTS_BUCKET=(S3 bucket name from step 2)
```

**4. Enable artifacts addon**

Finally, in your repository add the following lines to the `.travis.yml` in order to activate the artifacts addon

```
addons:
  artifacts: true
```

If everything went well, you should see your build artifacts popping up in the S3 bucket. You may want to adjust the paths being scanned and so on, as desecribed in [the documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/uploading-artifacts/).

Hope that helps someone or another.