# How to publish to Github Pages from Travis CI?

Tags: git, github, travis-ci, doxygen, github-pages

We are compiling Doxygen docs on the travis-ci server and want to push them onto our gh-pages branch.

How do I handle the authorization for `git push`? Does someone have an example for using encrypted variables in travis-ci? Should I go for https authorization or for an SSH key?

Comment: Superset: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343452/how-to-publish-artifacts-in-travis-ci

Comment: I found this site incredibly useful [Automatically Publish Javadoc to gh-pages with travis-ci](http://benlimmer.com/2013/12/26/automatically-publish-javadoc-to-gh-pages-with-travis-ci/)

This is the script that I'm using to do this for my build: https://github.com/WPIRoboticsProjects/GRIP/blob/master/.travis-scripts/push-javadoc-to-gh-pages.sh

Comment: What if we just want to publish compiled binaries to an existing GitHub Pages?

Comment: @StevenVascellarosame procedure, as with .html files

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Step-by-step example with HTTPS API Token in environment variable**

Others have mentioned it, but here goes a more detailed procedure.

1. Create a separate repository for the website (optional). This will reduce the likelihood that you overwrite your main repository, and will keep output files from polluting it.
2. Get a Personal Access Token under https://github.com/settings/tokens

   Only enable "public_repo" access for public repositories, "repo" for private.

   Save the token somewhere as you can only see it once.
3. On the Travis settings for the repository `https://travis-ci.org/<me>/<myrepo>/settings` create an environment variable:

   ```
   GITHUB_API_KEY=<token>
   ```

   and make sure to mark "Display value in build log" as "Off".

   This is safe because only authorized pushes by you see such environment variables, so if a malicious user tries to make a pull request to get your string, the variable won't be there.

   Just make sure that you never, ever list your environment variables on your build!
4. Add the following to your `.travis.yml`:

   ```
   after_success: |
     if [ -n "$GITHUB_API_KEY" ]; then
       cd "$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR"
       # This generates a `web` directory containing the website.
       make web
       cd web
       git init
       git checkout -b gh-pages
       git add .
       git -c user.name='travis' -c user.email='travis' commit -m init
       # Make sure to make the output quiet, or else the API token will leak!
       # This works because the API key can replace your password.
       git push -f -q https://<me>:$GITHUB_API_KEY@github.com/<me>/<myrepo>-gh-pages gh-pages &>/dev/null
       cd "$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR"
     fi
   ```

**Alternative travis encrypt method**

Explained in detail at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33109519/895245

Encrypt the string `GITHUB_API_KEY=<key>` with the `travis` gem, and add it to your `.travis.yml`:

```
env:
  secure: <encrypted>
```

This has the advantage that it does not require using the Travis web interface, but does require using a Gem and some more copy pasting.

Comment: This isn't helpful in the regard of pushing to a repository on another server (i.e. not GitHub).

Comment: @Arcrammer sure. But how could this question be interpreted for other servers? E.g.: does any other service support Travis CI?

Comment: Travis supports deployment with many services like Heroku and AWS as well as pushing to Git remotes and executing Bash scripts for deployment. I wanted to know how to push to a Git remote, but not a GitHub Git remote. I have a remote on my server. I've finally gotten it to work today! The challenging part was encrypting the SSH key for pushing to the remote through SSH and actually getting Travis to use the key.

Comment: Why use `|` after `after_success:` in step 4?

Comment: @nn0p that's just standard YAML multiline string notation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/in-yaml-how-do-i-break-a-string-over-multiple-lines

Comment: It is CRITICAL that you make sure your tokens don't leak. Note the `-q` flag passed to `git push`. `git push` and `git pull` often print the remote URL, which contains the GH token. I would go a step further and always pipe all output to `/dev/null` or store into a variable; I don't know what the behavior is of `git  push/pull` if an error is encountered with the `-q` flag, it may barf your token to stdout or stderr if this happens..

Comment: I think `https://<me>:$GITHUB_API_KEY@github.com` may need to be  `https://$GITHUB_API_KEY:@github.com` or  `https://$GITHUB_API_KEY@github.com`.

Comment: I think you mean `2>/dev/null` rather than `&2>/dev/null`.

Comment: I had to change the URL to `https://<me>:$GITHUB_API_KEY@github.com/<me>/<repo-name>.git` for it to work.

Answer (score 35):

I don't know how recent it is, but Travis now have a built-in deployment option, basically add to your travis file :

```
deploy:
  provider: pages
  skip_cleanup: true
  local_dir: myfolder/  # or remove this line to upload from root of repo
  github_token: $GITHUB_TOKEN # Set in travis-ci.org dashboard
  on:
    branch: master
```

Make sure you don't have a .gitignore in the uploaded folder ; it only uploads non ignored files.

See the online official doc from travis :
https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/pages/

There is no public key issue using "Repository Settings" approach, you generate a key in Github then copy paste it into secret/non visible fields of Travis.

**Upload history issue :**
Note that each upload crushes any previously uploaded data, without preserving history.

- You can now (Nov 2017+) instead preserve history by adding a `keep_history: true` line
- This may be desirable as these snapshot builds can be voluminous, and they are reproducible at will anyway (simply branch your depot back from the revision you want). Pointing to such artifacts is typically pointing to a last successful build of a snapshot.
- However to trigger storage to a stable place, simply edit your travis to add flag :
  target_branch: Branch to push force to, defaults to gh-pages
  E.g **target_branch : rc1.2**

And run it once before setting it back to snapshot mode.

Another alternative that might be good for releases (I haven't personally tested though) is to publish to a Tag see : https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/releases/

Comment: Drawbacks:

(1) Needs a _personal access token_ from GitHub, unnecessarily granting access to all repos of the user.

(2) Overwrites the target repo branch without preserving git history.

Comment: Concerning (1) it's not so much of a problem, travis is not going to mess with any other repos you have except for the one concerned by the build. The issue was making it public, it's private and shared only to travis, that you trust implicitly since it's making the upload. (2) is actually desirable, you don't want to store the history of binary results of the build. Just tag revisions for release.

Comment: There is a repo of example using this solution?

Comment: @ManoelVilela here is a production example, that uploads to a different place (branch) the MacOS and linux targets. https://github.com/lip6/libDDD/blob/master/.travis.yml

Answer (score 12):

The [travis-ci documentation here](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/custom/) recommends adding this to push to a git repo:

```
after_success:
   - chmod 600 .travis/deploy_key.pem # this key should have push access
   - ssh-add .travis/deploy_key.pem
   - git remote add deploy DEPLOY_REPO_URI_GOES_HERE
   - git push deploy
```

However, **this is insecure** as it has you store your unprotected private key in the github repository.

Instead you can add your ssh key as a [encrypted environmental variable](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/) using the travis tool:

```
travis encrypt DEPLOY_KEY=<private ssh key with write access> --add env.matrix
```

Now you just need to add this line to the beginning of after_success:

```
cat $DEPLOY_KEY > .travis/deploy_key.pem
```

Please note that after_success will toggle in every build in the build matrix so if you have multiple jobs per build your code will get pushed multiple times, which won't do anything but is good to know that it is occurring.

Comment: i will try this out - please stand by for the star

Comment: the key was too long for secured env variable, see my alternative solution

Comment: I solved the problem of key too long using the option of encrypting the file: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encrypting-files/

Comment: This looks promising, but how in the world did you figure this out? Their docs are very... Barebones in all of the wrong ways...

Comment: How do the deployment just on approved PR, which means on merge event.
I saw the use of $TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST but I dont want to deploy on each PR, just on approved PR.

Answer (score 10):

Just to add another solution, I used a HTTPS token from github, encrypted it and used HTTPS for checkouts and pushes

Comment: I would vote for this being a better solution. To make the token, go to Account settings -> Applications -> Generate Token.

There is a nice guide here: https://medium.com/@nthgergo/publishing-gh-pages-with-travis-ci-53a8270e87db

Comment: Note that HTTPS tokens cannot be limited to one repo. But since the token is stored encrypted and you are the only one who should have access to Travis CI it should not matter.

Comment: So, how does your final solution look like?

Comment: @okutane https://github.com/open62541/open62541/blob/0.2/tools/travis/travis_push_doc.sh

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a blog about this some days ago. Here's the brief:

I wrote [a custom deploy script](https://github.com/iBug/iBug-source/blob/master/.travis/deploy.sh) for this purpose. The core functionality of the script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

git clone --depth=1 --branch=master "https://github.com/iBug/iBug.github.io.git" deploy
cd deploy
git rm -rf .
cd ..
mv _site/* deploy
cd deploy
git add --all
git config user.name "Travis CI"
git config user.email "travis@travis-ci.org"
git commit --message "Auto deploy from Travis CI"
git remote add deploy "https://$GH_TOKEN@github.com/iBug/iBug.github.io.git" &>/dev/null
git push deploy master &>/dev/null
```

Now go to https://github.com/settings/tokens and generate a token. Grant it `public_repo` privilege. Go to repository settings on Travis CI and store the token with the variable name being `GH_TOKEN`.

Add the deploy script to travis:

```
script: bundle exec jekyll build
after_success:
    - bash .travis/deploy.sh
```

Push these things to GitHub and Travis will be triggered.

---

My blog is [here](https://ibug.github.io/p/4). It's comprehensive and thus redundant if posted as an answer here (because Stack Overflow users are mostly experienced developers). The script I posted in my blog also lacks a functionality: It does not preserve commit history of the built site, whereas the script in this answer above does.