# git: fatal: Could not read from remote repository when cloning Private Cocoapod

Tags: ios, git, cocoapods, travis-ci

I am trying to set up an iOS project on Travis-CI for the first time, and I am having trouble getting travis to add a private pod-spec repo.

I've got a before-script that runs this command:

```
- gem install cocoapods
- pod repo add MyPrivate-Repo git@github.com:myAccount/MyPrivate-Repo.git
...
```

However, I am getting this error when travis tries to add my private pod spec repo

```
Cloning spec repo `MyPrivate-Repo` from `git@github.com:myAccount/MyPrivate-Repo.git`

[!] Pod::Executable clone 'git@github.com:myAccount/MyPrivate-Repo.git' MyPrivate-Repo

Cloning into 'MyPrivate-Repo'...

ERROR: Repository not found.

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Now i am very new to this so apologies if I am missing something obvious here.

I am sure that the repository does indeed exist, I tested that by performing a

```
git clone git@github.com:myAccount/MyPrivate-Repo.git
```

on my local machine. So that means access rights I assume. How do I go about checking the access rights for that? Travis seems to work fine cloning other repos within the same organization? Any help much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works on your machine, because ssh knows where tyo look for your public/private ssh keys.

But you need to add those keys (or, even better, add a new public/ssh key dedicated to your travis config) to Travis, in order for that environment to be able to authenticate and access your private repo.

See [Pushing to github from travis-ci](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23284673/6309).

Note that you can use [`travis encrypt`](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/) in `.travis.yml` file as in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/lukewpatterson/4242707) from [Luke Patterson (`lukewpatterson`)](https://github.com/lukewpatterson).

> To encrypt the private SSH key into the "`-secure: xxxxx.....`" lines to place in the `.travis.yml` file, generate a **deploy key** then run: (to see what the encrypted data looks like, see an example in [this `.travis.yml`](https://github.com/veewee-community/veewee-push/blob/486102e6f508214b04414074c921475e5943f682/.travis.yml#L21).

```
base64 --wrap=0 ~/.ssh/id_rsa > ~/.ssh/id_rsa_base64
ENCRYPTION_FILTER="echo \$(echo \"-\")\$(travis encrypt veewee-community/veewee-push \"\$FILE='\`cat $FILE\`'\" | grep secure:)"
split --bytes=100 --numeric-suffixes --suffix-length=2 --filter="$ENCRYPTION_FILTER" ~/.ssh/id_rsa_base64 id_rsa_
```

> Ha! it takes 30 lines to squeeze it all in.

That gives something like:

```
env:
  global:
    - secure: "Y3Ox1GnYemOXPms5qUg//pnJBTh/9/kdnDa8BRXqurMaH6RuADcZnmSLjR7W\ny81/JuXMgToWN/+6zZALZyoYm87qRjjQAKfglA9nuSeXDSPhpERMXaf7RVUI\n8BpQYkmdY/HsQtGci4qqNfifQulp8TS/CpV+Kgx9k5JpulBeFow="
    - secure: "ePKK/XhvRqBiHKFPZdh5rGgupABVQyYUQWvl2uzfqgCRZ6xGIU+ZW89iiL27\n3cSfEL1x1FAXPkpslNOscz4INYgl8+dUvnmwnSuT2b/9ekpeDEhTmC+L06si\n15NLKCK7TUnS3wJ/WkA27ij43X+ArOqsTi2xvTXTPdn4utLjfIM="
    - secure: "C...
    ...
    ...
```

> To reconstitute the private SSH key once running inside Travis: (see example use [in this `.travis.yml`](https://github.com/veewee-community/veewee-push/blob/486102e6f508214b04414074c921475e5943f682/.travis.yml#L7-L13))

---

Another similar technique [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/douglasduteil/5525750) from [Douglas Duteil (`douglasduteil`)](https://github.com/douglasduteil), which declares in `.travis.yml` an *external* script.

```
before_script: .travis/before_script.sh



echo -n $id_rsa_{00..30} >> ~/.ssh/id_rsa_base64
base64 --decode --ignore-garbage ~/.ssh/id_rsa_base64 > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
echo -e "Host github.com\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n" >> ~/.ssh/config
```

Comment: Same situation is for me but i am not using any travis just try to add a local project. How to resolve that?

Comment: @kidsid49 you could create a new question, with a link back to this one, explaining the differences, and detailling your setup (git version, os, ...)

Comment: Here it is. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052755/how-to-add-a-private-spec-repo-for-using-private-pods

Comment: @kidsid49 great, but I don't see any information there about your setup, version number or error message that you could have had. You need to post a *complete* question for people to help you.

Comment: Sorry Man. Just edited my answer. I posted the whole terminal command and output.

Comment: @kidsid49 much better. Still missing the setup info (version of OS, git, other tools), but you are getting there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58403/discussion-between-kidsid49-and-vonc).