# How to add a private Spec Repo for using private pods?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoapods

I went through this tutorial http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html but coun't get any hint like how to create it. 
Its just shows what would be the structure only.

On the other side if i try to run  pod install this came.
Here i am trying to install sample-pod (Private pod) to one of my local project.

```
siddarths-MacBook-P:PodInstallDemoApp siddarthchaturvedi$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Pre-downloading: `sample-pod` from `git@github.com:MY_COMAPNY_NAME/sample-pod.git`
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/siddarthchaturvedi/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/siddarthchaturvedi/.ssh/id_rsa': 
[!] /usr/bin/git clone git@github.com:MY_COMPANY_NAME/sample-pod.git   /Users/siddarthchaturvedi/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/GitHub/8ce0f86807ab15b9f8d51bb9d2026cc102ba51aa --mirror

Cloning into bare repository    '/Users/siddarthchaturvedi/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/GitHub/8ce0f86807ab15b9f8d51bb9d2026cc102ba51aa'...

Saving password to keychain failed

Permission denied (publickey).

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.



 Please make sure you have the correct access rights

 and the repository exists.
```

For more details :- OS - Mac OSX 10.9 using latest version of cocoapods.
                    git version 1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)

Comment: If you are using two-factor-authentication, could be that. This article has a walk through to solve https://medium.com/@ginnyfahs/github-error-authentication-failed-from-command-line-3a545bfd0ca8

Answer (score 16):

You need to create your own Podspec repo which will contain your .podspec files.

Then use the following command to let CocoaPods know where your private repo is:

```
pod repo add <YourPivatePodsName> <YourPodRepoURL>
```

For Example:

```
pod repo add MyPrivatePods git@bitbucket.org:yourname/podspec.git
```

Comment: How can i  mirror this structure.
├── Specs
    └── [SPEC_NAME]
        └── [VERSION]
            └── [SPEC_NAME].podspec  like i have to create manually these folders in github online.

Comment: @kidsid49 Clone the repo using SourceTree, add folders and files and push.

Comment: Does anyone know the command to update your local private repo?

Comment: @WalterMartinVargas-Pena is [pod repo update](https://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#pod_repo_update) what you are looking for?

Comment: @Adam  is that "MyPrivatePods" repo different from the one which we have created earlier and pushed our data to? if yes, then what things will be pushed to this private repo?

Comment: @Saty this repo contains only the `podspec` files. You create a folder for each pod and within that folder you create subfolder for each version. These subfolders contain the `podspec` files. See [the public repo](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/tree/master/Specs) for an example.