# Encrypting files for travis-ci on ruby-2.2.2 fails with "private method `load' called for Psych:Module"

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, encryption, travis-ci, ruby-2.2

I'm having trouble encrypting my `database.yml` for Travis CI. Based on their [documentation, it appears you encrypt files with the travis encrypt-file command](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encrypting-files/). I'm running on Ruby-2.2.2 and it's giving me some pretty cryptic error messages.

```
travis encrypt-file config/database.yml --add
```

And I get this error:

```
private method `load' called for Psych:Module
for a full error report, run travis report
```

Here's the backtrace when I run `travis report`:

```
$ travis report 

/Users/William.Jeffries/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/travis-1.7.7/lib/travis/cli/api_command.rb:150:in `default_endpoint': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from /Users/William.Jeffries/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/travis-1.7.7/lib/travis/cli/api_command.rb:154:in `detected_endpoint'
        from /Users/William.Jeffries/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/travis-1.7.7/lib/travis/cli/api_command.rb:70:in `detected_endpoint?'
        from /Users/William.Jeffries/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/travis-1.7.7/lib/travis/cli/api_command.rb:158:in `endpoint_option'
        from /Users/William.Jeffries/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/travis-1.7.7/lib/travis/cli/command.rb:213:in `rescue in execute'
        from /Users/William.Jeffries/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/travis-1.7.7/lib/travis/cli/command.rb:191:in `execute'
        from /Users/William.Jeffries/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/travis-1.7.7/lib/travis/cli.rb:64:in `run'
        from /Users/William.Jeffries/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/travis-1.7.7/bin/travis:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/William.Jeffries/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/travis:23:in `load'
        from /Users/William.Jeffries/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/travis:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: You might want to check [this github issue](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/issues/1510). What version of `Psych` do you use? Reverting the `Psych` gem to `2.0.5` seems to be a solution. Or you might want to try the latest version - the current one is `2.0.13`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to uninstall `Psych` version `2.0.13` and have only `2.0.5` on my machine. I had both `2.0.5` and `2.0.13` and it seems that they were conflicting with each other. I found the information on [this forum post](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/issues/1510).

Comment: @spickermann thank you for pointing me to the github issue that had the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
gem update --system
```

solved it for me on Ubuntu 14.04 + RVM + Ruby 2.1.1p76 as mentioned at: https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/issues/1510#issuecomment-102645627