# Download build from Travis

Tags: travis-ci

Is there a way to download latest compiled travis binary? I want to try the unreleased version, but I can't compile it by myself.

Is there a button to download the compiled software?

Comment: @jmattheis any compiled application, I guess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to publish artifacts in Travis CI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343452/how-to-publish-artifacts-in-travis-ci)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Travis doesn't compile binaries and save them, it just compiles them and makes sure they can be compiled without errors.

**EDIT**: Yes, it does, if the project owners want Travis to do so! See this: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/releases/