# How to retain generated artifacts with travis.ci?

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci, artifact

On this [project](https://github.com/heig-vd-tin/refcard) I have configured a minimal `.travis.yml` to build my LaTeX project. I would TravisCI to retain the latest PDF file generated.

How can I tell TravisCI to retain some output files?

Comment: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/uploading-artifacts/?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Unfortunately this only work with `Amazon S3` :(

Comment: That is correct. If you want to upload files to somewhere else, have you done anything about that?

Comment: I would like TravisCI to retain those artifacts at the end of a build the same way TeamCity does.

Comment: Well those are two different products entirely. Travis supports the aforementioned S3 upload or some form of deployment (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/12343452/3001761, https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment). You can run an arbitrary script to do whatever else you need.